# Process.Start() unable to find javac, even though it is in PATH

Tags: c#, path, environment-variables, javac, process.start

I am trying to compile Java from a C# console application using `Process.Start()`. Here is my code:

```
static string ProjectRootDirectory
{
    get
    {
        return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\.."));
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        FileName = "javac", 
        Arguments = Path.Combine(ProjectRootDirectory, @"Java\Main.java"), 
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    var proc = Process.Start(info);
    using (var reader = proc.StandardOutput)
    {
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get a `Win32Exception` on `Process.Start()` because it says `"The system cannot find the file specified."` However, I have already set by `PATH` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\` . Here is my full `PATH` (Java path found at end):

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\James\utils\bash\;C:\Users\James\utils\batch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\
```

And here is the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable my `PATH` references:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\
```

**When I type `javac [file]` into the command prompt manually, it works fine.** But in `Process.Start()`, I have to specify the full path of `javac`. Any idea why?

**EDIT:** Following [Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437207/c-sharp-process-start-unable-to-find-javac-even-though-it-is-in-path?noredirect=1#comment47044202_29437207)'s suggestion, I have found out that `PATH` is indeed seen differently by the current process. Printing `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)` results in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries/x86;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\James\utils\bash\;C:\Users\James\utils\batch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\
```

which seems to be excluding the path for `javac`.

Comment: Put a watch on Path.Combine(ProjectRootDirectory, @"Java\Main.java") and look at what the string actually is

Comment: I get the correct path, [project directory]\Java\Main.java . Also, Process.Start() is saying that it can't find javac.exe, not the path of the .java file.

Comment: Obvious debug step would be dump PATH variable as seen by C# process before calling `.Start`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you. I have updated the answer with additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely reason of seeing different path:

You launch VS (and correspondingly application) from desktop shortcut (or start menu) which uses default path. You launch command prompt with additional CMD configuration file which adds more paths.

Fixes:

- update system-wide PATH variable to include javac path
- launch VS (devenv.exe) from the same command prompt you get correct PATH variable from
- launch your program from the same command prompt you get correct PATH variable from (instead of VS).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify: the `PATH` variable I posted in my initial post was copied and pasted straight from the Environment Variables dialog, so that _was_ my system-wide `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Fix: I hadn't closed Visual Studio since I updated my `PATH`.

Sometimes, the solution can be the simplest thing...